# Subtracting rows in R based on matching value

Tags: r

I am trying to substract two rows in my dataset from each other:

```
Name Period    Time     Distance  Load
Tim    A     01:06:20    6000     680
Max    A     01:06:20    5000     600
Leo    A     01:06:20    5500     640
Noa    A     01:06:20    6500     700
Tim    B     00:04:10    500      80
Max    B     00:04:10    500      50
Leo    B     00:04:10    400      40
```

I want to subtract the Time, Distance and Load values of Period B from Period A for matching Names.
eg. Subtract row 5 (Tim, Period B) from row 1 (Tim, Period A)
The new values should be written into a new table looking like this:

```
Name Period    Time     Distance  Load
Tim    C     01:02:10    5500     600
Max    C     01:02:10    4500     550
Leo    C     01:02:10    5100     600
Noa    C     01:06:20    6500     700
```

The real dataset contains many more rows. I tried to play around with dplyr but could not get the result I am looking for.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're missing Noa in Period B. Was that intentional?

Comment: Yes that was intentional.
I should have clarified. Period B is part of Period A. But not every player (Name) has a Period B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many answers already that this is just a bit of fun at this stage. I think this way is nice as it uses `unnest_wider()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

diff <- function(data) {
        if(apply(data[2, -1], 1, function(x) all(is.na(x)))) {
                data[1, -1]
        } else {
                data[1, -1] - data[2, -1]
        }
}

df %>% group_by(Name) %>% nest() %>%
        mutate(diff = map(data, diff)) %>% unnest_wider(diff) %>%
        mutate(Period = "C") %>% select(Period, Time, Distance, Load)
```

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  Name  Period Time     Distance  Load
  <chr> <chr>  <time>      <dbl> <dbl>
1 Tim   C      01:02:10     5500   600
2 Max   C      01:02:10     4500   550
3 Leo   C      01:02:10     5100   600
4 Noa   C      01:06:20     6500   700
```

Apart from the `diff()` function (which can probably be made neater and 'exclusively' `tidyverse`), this way is also shorter.

---

**DATA**

```
library(readr)

# courtesy of @MartinGal
df <- read_table2("Name Period    Time     Distance  Load
Tim    A     01:06:20    6000     680
Max    A     01:06:20    5000     600
Leo    A     01:06:20    5500     640
Noa    A     01:06:20    6500     700
Tim    B     00:04:10    500      80
Max    B     00:04:10    500      50
Leo    B     00:04:10    400      40")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could filter on the two periods and then join them together, thus facilitating the subtraction of columns.

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(filter(df, Period=="A"), filter(df, Period=="B"), by="Name") %>%
  mutate(Period="C",
         Time=Time.x-Time.y,
         Distance=Distance.x-Distance.y,
         Load=Load.x-Load.y) %>%
  select(Name, Period, Time, Distance, Load)
```

---

```
  Name Period           Time Distance Load
1  Tim      C 1.036111 hours     5500  600
2  Max      C 1.036111 hours     4500  550
3  Leo      C 1.036111 hours     5100  600
```

Answer (score 1):

It's basically the same idea as @Edward. You could use `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```r
df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from="Period", values_from=c("Time", "Distance", "Load")) %>%
  mutate(Period = "C",
         Time = coalesce(Time_A - Time_B, Time_A),
         Distance = coalesce(Distance_A - Distance_B, Distance_A),
         Load = coalesce(Load_A - Load_B, Load_A)
         ) %>%
  select(-matches("_\\w"))
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  Name  Period Time     Distance  Load
  <chr> <chr>  <time>      <dbl> <dbl>
1 Tim   C      01:02:10     5500   600
2 Max   C      01:02:10     4500   550
3 Leo   C      01:02:10     5100   600
4 Noa   C      01:06:20     6500   700
```

---

Data

```r
df <- read_table2("Name Period    Time     Distance  Load
Tim    A     01:06:20    6000     680
Max    A     01:06:20    5000     600
Leo    A     01:06:20    5500     640
Noa    A     01:06:20    6500     700
Tim    B     00:04:10    500      80
Max    B     00:04:10    500      50
Leo    B     00:04:10    400      40")
```

Comment: How did you write the data so that `Time` has class `<time>` in the tibble? I tried using `lubridate::hms()` on a character string (e.g. `"01:06:20"`) but the tibble sees this as `<Period>`

Comment: I just imported Tizian's data by using `read_table2` (see edited answer). The class was automatically assigned.

Comment: Awesome thanks! This is the function I was missing to recreate data that isn't supplied with `dput()`.

Comment: In many cases this function works fine. But sometimes you have to process the data further to get the original data input.

Comment: I see, thank you @Martin, in any case, this will make my life a lot easier. As for the time issue, I tried using the `times()` function from the `chron` package that @Chris uses in his answer, and a tibble now sees this as `<times>' and not as `<time>` as in your example... Time (and date) objects in R are still really confusing for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach which groups by `Name` to get the difference.

```
library(dplyr)
library(chron)

df <- structure(list(Name = structure(c(4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Leo", "Max", "Noa", "Tim"), class = "factor"), 
                     Period = structure(c(1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
                     Time = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0:04:10", "1:06:20"), class = "factor"), 
                     Distance = c(6000L, 5000L, 5500L, 6500L, 500L, 500L, 400L), 
                     Load = c(680L, 600L, 640L, 700L, 80L, 50L, 40L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

df %>% 
  mutate(Time = times(Time)) %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  mutate(Time = lag(Time) - Time,
         Distance = lag(Distance) - Distance,
         Load = lag(Load) - Load,
         Period = LETTERS[which(LETTERS == Period) + 1]) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Time))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use data.table too.

```
dt <- data.table(Name = c('Tim', 'Max', 'Leo', 'Noa', 'Tim', 'Max', 'Leo'),
             Period = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'), 
             Time = c('01:06:20', '01:06:20' , '01:06:20' , '01:06:20' , '00:04:10' , '00:04:10' , '00:04:10' ),
             Distance = c(6000, 5000, 5500, 6500, 500, 500, 400 ),
             Load = c(680, 600, 640, 700, 80, 50, 40))
```

Then the first thing to do is to convert the Time var:

```
dt[, Time := as.POSIXct(Time, format = "%H:%M:%S")]
sapply(dt, class)
```

Then you use dcast.data.table:

```
dtCast <- dcast.data.table(dt, Name ~ Period, value.var = c('Time', 'Distance', 'Load'))
```

And then you create a new object:

```
dtFinal <- dtCast[,list(Period = 'C',
                        Time = Time_A - Time_B,
                        Distance = Distance_A - Distance_B,
                        Load = Load_A - Load_B),
                  by = 'Name']
```

Mind that if you want to convert the Time to the same format as above, you need to do the following:

```
library(hms)
dtFinal[, Time := as_hms(Time)]
```